# Request blocked when I try to use a google font

Tags: html, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I get the message when I try to use a google font

Request for access to cookies or storage for "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" has been blocked because all requests for memory access for non-directly-accessed websites (third-party providers) are blocked and blocking of page elements is enabled.

I used Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: are you importing via an @ import statement or an html <link>? I've personally has a LOT of trouble importing via the link tag and have alleviated most of my issues by switching to a css import at the top of my CSS document

Comment: Check if your browser is blocking third party cookies. If content blocking is enabled, turn it off.